Problems with security group in aws copilot service
I'm using aws copilot to deploy some microservices and an ALB
I created an environment with copilot env init choosing an existing VPC, public and private subnets
Then I started to create the 1st microservice that need a connection to a already existent RDS Mysql database.
What is the right way to do this?
I mean, if the service doesn't exist, copilot create a manifest.yml file with all settings, but it doesn't include anything about SG for connecting to RDS. After service has been created, it's created also a SG for it. Then I can manually add this SG to my RDS.
If the manifest was already created, I can modify it adding a SG id, but if I add a SG that is already configured in RDS, will it work? I mean, a SG is a list of rules that enable connection from an IP, or from other SG. If my already existent SG for RDS has 1 rule that enable connection from ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, why defining this SG inside service manifest should work???
So my problem is how to automate deploy process (maybe with a pipeline later) using the right SG without doing anything by hand.
Thanks

It sounds like the RDS database already exists and you need to modify its inbound SG rules to allow traffic from your newly-deployed app. Wouldn't that RDS SG modification logically belong in the automation (or manual process) that created the database?

If I want to manage a deploy with a CI/CD, everything should be automatic. And yes, that modification should be part of this process, but I don't know how to do that.
